# Is there any harm in using a fake domain as location in MHTML?

Tags: mhtml

I'm generating mhtml files to package a local page into a single file.

At first, reading the specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557 it seemed to me that I can just ditch location all together and use relative paths but I'm running into security errors with that, I get the error "Not allowed to load local resource: file://..."

This is when the file looks like this:

```
From: <MHTML Generator>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB"; type="text/html"

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PC9oZWFkPjxib2R5Pg0KPGltZyBzcmM9InBpY3Mvb2sucG5nIj4NClRlc3QhISBoZXJlIEkgYW0NCjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB
Content-Location: pics/ok.png
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

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

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB--
```

However, if I add a fake base location:

```
From: <MHTML Generator>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB"; type="text/html"

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB
Content-Location: https://fake.com
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PC9oZWFkPjxib2R5Pg0KPGltZyBzcmM9InBpY3Mvb2sucG5nIj4NClRlc3QhISBoZXJlIEkgYW0NCjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB
Content-Location: https://fake.com/pics/ok.png
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

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

--boundary_N7JVHbsWDzwnj6aXjmh4dZq33fjuicQy24LSKDEMrUmXONq4oO1zW1EYSQ3C38OB--
```

Then everything works good. I cannot find the fake domain expressed anywhere during runtime so.. I'm inclined to just use this hack. Does anyone know of any downsides?